# Persistence with localStorage with useState and useContext React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks, use-state, use-context

I have set up a Provider to share some state for a user using `useContext`. As such I am trying to leverage local storage to save some state for a users images (avatars, etc.)

To start I'm tryingto persist the avatar for a user, essentially saving their ID from express and then using it when I make a call to Cloudinary (an image hosting service).

I think I'm close (as I get the default image-placeholder for the avatar to work) but I can't set the local storage.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

var initialState = {
  userId: null,
  avatar: '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg'
};

var UserContext = React.createContext();

function getLocalStorage() {
  return Object.keys(initialState).forEach(item => {
    dynamic(
      () =>
        Object.keys(initialState).forEach(
          val => (initialState[window.localStorage.getItem(item)] = val)
        ),
      {
        ssr: false
      }
    );
  });
}

function setLocalStorage() {
  Object.keys(initialState).forEach(item => {
    console.log('item setLocalStorage', item);
    dynamic(
      () =>
        window.localStorage.setItem(
          item,
          Object.values(initialState).forEach(item => item)
        ),
      {
        ssr: false
      }
    );
  });
}

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  var [userImages, setUserImages] = useState(() => getLocalStorage() || initialState);

  var [userId, setUserId] = useState(userImages.userId);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage();
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        userImages,
        setUserImages,
        userId,
        setUserId
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserContext;

export { UserProvider };
```

Thank you in advance, Happy Father's day!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe `next/dynamic` is not needed in this scenario. ES2020 `dynamic import()` is for importing JavaScript modules (inc. React Components) dynamically. Here you are not importing anything.

Also, keys and values in `localStorage` are always in string format. That's why you may skip `null` value(or it will be converted to string "null"). I'd suggest you to store the whole user state as an object by using `JSON.stringify`.

So the `setLocalStorage()` and `getLocalStorage()` will be:

```
function setLocalStorage(key, value) {
  try {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (e) {
    // catch possible errors:
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API
  }
}

function getLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  try {
    const value = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    return value ? JSON.parse(value) : initialValue;
  } catch (e) {
    // if error, return initial value
    return initialValue;
  }
}
```

Then, you may use them in the `UserProvider` as followed:

```
function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => getLocalStorage("user", initialState));

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage("user", user);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        userId: user.id,
        userAvatar: user.avatar,
        userImages: user.images,
        setUserId: (id) => setUser({ ...user, id }),
        setUserAvatar: (avatar) => setUser({ ...user, avatar }),
        setUserImages: (images) => setUser({ ...user, images }),
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It really help me understand localStorage better!

Comment: I want to give a special thanks to @Hangindev as this is really amazing and simple solution that made my application work!!!!! Thanky so much!!!!

Comment: Lol. This is better explanation than react, nextjs and pretty much rest of internet. Well done hangindev.com!